# UIScrollView zoom uiview to aspect fill

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have an image in the UIScrollView and I'm trying to make it aspect fill by default, the code below scale it as listed on the first attached image. But it's not what I expect, how to scale it properly?

```
    func aspectFill() {
        let imageSize = imageZoomView.bounds.size

        let xScale = bounds.width / imageSize.width
        let yScale = bounds.height / imageSize.height

        zoomScale = max(xScale, yScale)
    }
```

[image: UIScrollView zoom uiview to aspect fill]

But the expected result is

[image: expeced result]

Comment: Is there a specific reason for adding the UIImageView inside a scrollView, instead of just giving aspect fill content mode for the UIImageView itself?

Comment: i think he wants to add zoom and pinch

Comment: yep, I put the uiimage into scroll view in order to have ability to zoom and i want scale it to fill by default

Comment: @YehorChernenko - do you want the image to *start* at aspectFill, but also allow zooming-down to show the full image? Or do you want minimum zoom scale to remain aspect-fill?

Comment: yes! I would like to start in the aspect fill and allow zoom-down to show full image

Answer (score 0):

Solution for both vertical and landscape image orientations:

```
let widthRatio = sourseImageSize.width / sourseImageSize.height
let height = scrollView.bounds.width / widthRatio
let zoomScaleH = scrollView.bounds.height / height
    
let heightRatio = sourseImageSize.height / sourseImageSize.width
let width = scrollView.bounds.height / heightRatio
let zoomScaleW = scrollView.bounds.width / width

let scaleResult = max(zoomScaleH, zoomScaleW)

scrollView.setZoomScale(scaleResult, animated: false)
```